# Does running a PID Autotune with an increased cycle count result in more accurate PID values?

Tags: temperature, pid, mriscoc

I'm using the mriscoc firmware for Creality Ender 3 V2. The firmware has the option to run more PID Autotune cycles. The default is 5 cycles. Does running a PID Autotune with an increased cycle count result in more accurate PID values? For example running 50 cycles instead of the default 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **yes**, More PID cycles will generally yield 'better' results.

However, the PID values are being averaged over these multiple runs, and it will very quickly pass the point of diminishing returns after 5 cycles, Hence why it is the default.

By the time you reach the hypothetical 50 cycles, you have likely far exceeded the margin of error present as a result of tolerances in your setup, and are only averaging noise.

Comment: An interesting question that may arise from your answer is why better results are generated by doing more than one cycle.